# How to download data in json from firebase storage?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use data of Firebase Real Time database locally for my project, Is there any way to download data in json from Firebase Real Time database *using python script*?

Answer (score 2):

*It is not 100% clear if your question is about the Firebase Real Time database (as the tags of your question show) or about Firebase Storage (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/).*

If your question is about the Realtime Database, you could  use the Realtime Database REST API, which returns data from the database in JSON format.

The documentation for retrieving data is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data